# Add Icon Variable to docker-compose.yml for Minecraft Server Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm trying to setup a Docker Minecraft Server with [itzg's minecraft-server](https://itzg/docker-minecraft-server). The first attempt worked great and I already played a little.

**Setup**

Now I want to upgrade the visuals with a server icon. I'm using docker-compose (file name "docker-compose.yml") to spin up the container which looks like this:

```
services:
    minecraft:
        # which image you want to pull (you may add :latest)
        image: itzg/minecraft-server
        container_name: minecraft-server
        # mount the data container to a accessable file
        volumes:
            - ~/Documents/docker/Minecraft:/data
        ports:
            - 25565:25565
        environment:
            # neccessary
            EULA: "TRUE"
            # recomended
            OPS: "duxt3r__"
            ENABLE_WHITELIST: "TRUE"
            ENFORCE_WHITELIST: "TRUE"
            MEMORY: "4G"
            # optional
            VERSION: "1.20.2"
            TYPE: "BUKKIT"
            MOTD: "\u00A7lVersion \u00A76[1.20.2] \u00A70--- !SURVIVAL! --- Version \u00A7a0.2 \u00A77patch:RAM=4GB, Cosmetics\u00A7r\n(server is currently in ALPHA version)"
            MAX_PLAYERS: 10
            ICON: ~/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png
            
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        # try restarting 3 times if container fails
        restart: on-failure:3
```

**Problem**

When I try to start the server with `sudo docker-compose up -d` the Portainer console outputs

```
[init] ERROR: /home/ubuntu/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png does not appear to be a URL or existing file
```

Can anyone explain to me what I do wrong and provide a Solution?

**I have tried...**

1. ... changing the filename to "server-icon.png" cause in the server files it's supposed to be named like this and check the image dimensions. But this shouldn't make any difference since the [documentation states](https://docker-minecraft-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variables/#server) (under "ICON") that the file is automatically "scaled, and converted to the proper format".
2. ...different paths:

```
~/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png
/home/ubuntu/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png
home/ubuntu/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png
https://home/ubuntu/Documents/docker/Minecraft/server-icon.png
```

3. I double checked if the server-icon.png is in the correct location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the container, that file exists in the /data/ directory because that's where you mapped the volume to.  Try setting the env variable to  /data/server-icon.png